# Function to creates buttons

Tags: supercollider

I'm trying to create a function to create a button (so keep the "clean" code).

Here is the code:

```
(
Window.closeAll;

~w = Window.new(
    name: "Xylophone",
    resizable: true,
    border: true,
    server: s,
    scroll: false);

~w.alwaysOnTop = true; 

/**
 * Function that creates a button.
 */
createButtonFunc = {
    |
        l = 20, t = 20, w = 40, h = 190, // button position
        nameNote = "note", // button name
        freqs // frequency to play
    |

    Button(
        parent: ~w, // the parent view
        bounds: Rect(left: l, top: t, width: w, height: h)
    )
    .states_([[nameNote, Color.black, Color.fromHexString("#FF0000")]])
    .action_({Synth("xyl", [\freqs, freqs])});
}
)


(
SynthDef("xyl", {
    |
        out = 0, // the index of the bus to write out to
        freqs = #[410], // array of filter frequencies
        rings = #[0.8] // array of 60 dB decay times in seconds for the filters 
    |

    ...
)
```

The error is: **ERROR: Variable 'createButtonFunc' not defined**.
Why?

Sorry but I'm a beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a little late to answer this, but I hope this might help someone else with the same question.

The reason you're getting that error is because you're using a variable name before you're declared it.

In other words, if you try to evaluate

`variableName`

on its own, you'll always get an error, because the interpreter can't match that name to anything else it knows. To solve this, you can use a global interpreter variable (`a`-`z`), an environment variable (like `~createButtonFunc`), or declare `var createButtonFunc` earlier on in your code. Note that this last one means you won't be able to access that variable name after interpreting that chunk, which may or may not be a good thing. If you want to be able to access it later, I think it makes the most sense to write `~createButtonFunc`.

By the way, you can just use `w` instead of `~w`; single-letter variable names are global by default, and that's the idiomatic usage.

-Brian